# How can I run a pb file? I have a pb file and i want to run the graph, all of it. Below is what i have tried

Tags: python, tensorflow

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
import sys
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saved_model_pb2
from tensorflow.python.util import compat

```
path='saved_model.pb'
log_dir='new_dir'
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename = path
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = compat.as_bytes(f.read())
        sm = saved_model_pb2.SavedModel()
        sm.ParseFromString(data)
        g_in = tf.import_graph_def(sm.meta_graphs[0].graph_def)
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir)
    train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load

Comment: Yeah. I have a software that only read pb file and does not support tf.model.save method. So i was wondering if it possible to execute the graph in other ways